# Is it possible to fix versions of packages installed via Conda-forge?

Tags: python, anaconda

We have open source software on Conda-forge channel and we are using old versions of `sci-kit-learn`, `matplotlib`, etc…

We are updating our software to use the latest version of those dependencies but is there any way to fix the versions of the dependencies on Conda-forge feedstock recipe to use older versions of packages like `sci-kit-learn`, `matplotlib`, etc… ?